# How to build Qt project, originally created in visual studio, in ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I have created new Qt5 project (Qt application) in visual studio.

Using visual studio Qt addin .pro file is generated, code is build and simple form is shown.
When i transfer that project to ubuntu, hosted on my virtualbox, Qt creator can't compile it.

It returns errors for almost every line.

Qt version 5.5
ubuntu 14.04
gcc compiler and all libs are installed.

Comment: Try using qmake directly and show the errors.

Comment: `if (!errors.empty()) { showErrors(); }`

Comment: Maybe you do not have the qt development libraries installed in linux. Maybe your pro file has windows paths.

Comment: all qt libs are installed and pro file is configured for linux, problem is that i want to compile trough windows using visualgdb plugin